# Can I add margin inside textarea?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if I could add some left margin inside textarea, I want there to be some space because I am using an image icon as my button and thats inside the textarea, when I type the words eventually cover the image.

```html
<div id="inputBox">
   <textarea class="txtarea" rows="50" name="Text" Id="Text"> </textarea>
   <button mat-button id="send">
     <mat-icon>send</mat-icon> 
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't add a margin inside, margin is by definition on the outside of the element. What you want is padding, specifically `padding-left`. See : https://medium.com/frontendshortcut/margin-vs-padding-c1fc8ea8bfaf

Answer (score 0):

always search google first
[Web development resource](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin.asp)

```
.txtarea{
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: While W3Schools can be helpful, it is by no means the "best resource." Also, you are likely to get better information if you look up a more specific question.

Comment: @Perhapsyouseethisname. I agree with you, wanted to point this person to some beginner level guide. I find W3schools is the go to guide